# How do I force scroll wheel events to only affect a canvas filled with BabylonJS

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, babylonjs

I have a web app that contains a canvas filled with a BabylonJS created scene (with an ArcRotateCamera) and other html content.
I want to use the scroll wheel of the mouse to zoom the camera in the canvas.
This works as long as the html content is not scrollable. As soon as the html becomes scrollable the scroll wheel affects both, the zoom of the canvas (that is what I want) and the part of the HTML page shown (this what I do not want here).
How could I prevent the scroll wheel from affecting the HTML contents (which ultimately scrolls the canvas offscreen)?

Comment: Not 100% familiar with babylon but can you just add an event listener on the canvas when the user scrolls and prevent the event from propagating? e.g. `canvas.addEventListener('wheel', e => { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation() });`